# Android Annotations EViewGroup unable to recognize EActivity in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, viewgroup, android-annotations

I have a class set up as an EViewGroup. In it, I'm trying to reference another Activity set up as an EActivity. For some reason, the import isn't resolving, but it resolves fine if I reference the Activity in question from another EActivity.

The code compiles fine using ant on our Jenkins server, but doesn't compile within Ecipse.

Any ideas?

Here's some code for ViewGroup:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EViewGroup;

@EViewGroup
public class MainMenu extends SlidingMenu
{

    public void navigate(Class<? extends Activity> klass)
    {
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), klass));
        toggle();
    }

    @Click(R.id.textView_bring_it)
    public void bringItClick()
    {
        navigate(ActivityBringIt_.class);
    }
}
```

The compile errors I'm seeing:

- The import com.beachbody.p90x.bringit.ActivityBringIt_ cannot be
  resolved
- The method navigate(Class) in the type MainMenu
  is not applicable for the arguments (Class)
- ActivityBringIt_ cannot be resolved to a type

Here is my .factorypath file:

```
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/common/compile-libs/androidannotations-2.7.1.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `ActivityBringIt_` isn't generated. Your compiling errors are just noises because of that.

Mostly AA can't generate subclasses if you have errors in you Android's xml files.
You should take a look on this.

Also, could you copy/paste your .factory file ?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I posted my .factorypath file. Is that what you meant? I don't see a .factory file.

Also, I looked in the .apt_generated folder and ActivityBringIt_ is there. It's referenced from other files just fine, just not from this file designated as an EViewGroup, but I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: Also, I don't see any errors in either the layout which MainMenu inflates or the layout which ActivityBringIt inflates.

Comment: Ok then. I my last project I have also this kind of issue and it was a problem in Eclipse's builders chain as explained [in the FAQ](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/FAQ#wiki-aspectj). Can you check this please ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks DayS for pointing me in the right direction. There is a bug in Eclipse causing this issue. The workaround is to import the entire package in question. In my case it is:

```
import com.beachbody.p90x.bringit.*;
```

Here is the bug report w/ Eclipse:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387956